# Trigger events from Firefox browser extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, dom-events

I want to trigger events from a Firefox extension, specifically click events. I've tried jQuery's `.click()` as well as the whole:

```
 var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
 evt.initEvent("click", true, false );
 toClick[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
```

This is not working for me, and I was wondering if this is even possible? (to trigger events from a Firefox extension)?

I think it may have something to do with what document I create the event on...but I'm not sure.

If so, how does one do it?

Comment: I apologize as your answer worked perfectly! I hope I awarded it in time.

Comment: don't worry, it was perfectly on time!, I'm glad my answer worked good for you, many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, for *click* events, you need to create an event object with type `MouseEvents`, not `HTMLEvents`, and use [`event.initMouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initMouseEvent) instead of `event.initEvent`.

To access the `document` of the current tab of Firefox from a XUL overlay, you can use the [`content.document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Working_with_windows_in_chrome_code#Content_windows) property, but since you already have access to the DOM element you want to click, you can use the [`Node.ownerDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.ownerDocument) property, which will refer to the top-level `document` object for this node.

I have made a simple function to simulate [MouseEvents](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MouseEvent):

```
function triggerMouseEvent(element, eventName, userOptions) {
  var options = { // defaults
    clientX: 0, clientY: 0, button: 0,
    ctrlKey: false, altKey: false, shiftKey: false,
    metaKey: false, bubbles: true, cancelable: true
     // create event object:
  }, event = element.ownerDocument.createEvent("MouseEvents");

  if (!/^(?:click|mouse(?:down|up|over|move|out))$/.test(eventName)) {
    throw new Error("Only MouseEvents supported");
  }

  if (typeof userOptions != 'undefined'){ // set the userOptions
    for (var prop in userOptions) {
      if (userOptions.hasOwnProperty(prop))
        options[prop] = userOptions[prop];
    }
  }
  // initialize the event object
  event.initMouseEvent(eventName, options.bubbles, options.cancelable,
                       element.ownerDocument.defaultView,  options.button,
                       options.clientX, options.clientY, options.clientX,
                       options.clientY, options.ctrlKey, options.altKey,
                       options.shiftKey, options.metaKey, options.button,
                       element);
  // dispatch!
  element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Usage:

```
triggerMouseEvent(element, 'click');
```

Check a test usage [here](http://jsbin.com/asahi3/edit).

You can pass also an object as the third argument, if you want to change the values of the [event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event) properties.

Comment: @Alex, since you already have the DOM element you want to *click*, we can use the `Node.ownerDocument` property instead of using `content.document`, try it out ;-)